# Create dummies for non-unique lists into column in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Currently I've the next dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame({"ID" : ['1','2','3','4','5'], 
                     "col2" : [['a', 'b', 'c'], 
                               ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], 
                               ['f', 'b', 'f'], 
                               ['a', 'c', 'b'], 
                               ['b', 'a', 'b']]})

print(df)
  ID          col2
0  1     [a, b, c]
1  2  [c, d, e, f]
2  3     [f, b, f]
3  4     [a, c, b]
4  5     [b, a, d]
```

I want to create a new dataframe with dummies for col2, like this:

```
    ID   a   b   c   d   e   f
0   1    1   1   1   0   0   0
1   2    0   0   1   1   1   1
2   3    0   1   0   0   0   1
3   4    1   1   1   0   0   0
4   5    1   1   0   1   0   0
```

Using the following code generates different columns for each of the letters in the column list:

```
df2= df.col2.str.get_dummies(sep = ",")
pd.concat([data['col1'], df], axis=1)

ID  a   b   b]  c   c]  d   d]  e   f]  [a [b  [c  [f
1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   0
3   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1
4   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
5   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0
```

Using the following code generates different columns for each of the letters in the list of the column according to the position in which they are. Does any of you have any idea why you might be going through this? The `pd.get_dummies` option also doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str.get_dummies` works well on strings so you can turn your list into a something-separated-string and use `str_get_dummies` on that string. For example,

```
df['col2'].str.join('@').str.get_dummies('@')
Out: 
   a  b  c  d  e  f
0  1  1  1  0  0  0
1  0  0  1  1  1  1
2  0  1  0  0  0  1
3  1  1  1  0  0  0
4  1  1  0  0  0  0
```

Here, `@` is an arbitrary character that does not appear in the list.

Then, you can concat as usual:

```
pd.concat([df['ID'], df['col2'].str.join('@').str.get_dummies('@')], axis=1)
Out: 
  ID  a  b  c  d  e  f
0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0
1  2  0  0  1  1  1  1
2  3  0  1  0  0  0  1
3  4  1  1  1  0  0  0
4  5  1  1  0  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 3):

Using comprehension dicts could be faster

```
In [40]: pd.DataFrame({k: 1 for k in x} for x in df.col2.values).fillna(0).astype(int)
Out[40]:
   a  b  c  d  e  f
0  1  1  1  0  0  0
1  0  0  1  1  1  1
2  0  1  0  0  0  1
3  1  1  1  0  0  0
4  1  1  0  0  0  0    

In [48]: pd.concat([
                df['ID'], 
                pd.DataFrame({k: 1 for k in x} for x in df.col2).fillna(0).astype(int)],
            axis=1)
Out[48]:
  ID  a  b  c  d  e  f
0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0
1  2  0  0  1  1  1  1
2  3  0  1  0  0  0  1
3  4  1  1  1  0  0  0
4  5  1  1  0  0  0  0
```

---

**Timings**

```
In [2942]: df.shape
Out[2942]: (50000, 2)

In [2945]: %timeit pd.DataFrame({k: 1 for k in x} for x in df.col2).fillna(0).astype(int)
10 loops, best of 3: 137 ms per loop

In [2946]: %timeit df['col2'].str.join('@').str.get_dummies('@')
1 loop, best of 3: 395 ms per loop
```

Comment: this is fantastic! It is much quicker and much more memory efficient!

Answer (score 1):

with the `df` you provided... this works fine

```
def f1(x):
    # 1 if exist
    return pd.Series(1, set(x))

def f2(x):
    # count occurences
    return pd.value_counts(x)

print(df.set_index('ID').col2.apply(f1).fillna(0).astype(int).reset_index())
print('')
print(df.set_index('ID').col2.apply(f2).fillna(0).astype(int).reset_index())

  ID  a  b  c  d  e  f
0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0
1  2  0  0  1  1  1  1
2  3  0  1  0  0  0  1
3  4  1  1  1  0  0  0
4  5  1  1  0  0  0  0

  ID  a  b  c  d  e  f
0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0
1  2  0  0  1  1  1  1
2  3  0  1  0  0  0  2
3  4  1  1  1  0  0  0
4  5  1  2  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: your problem was that in order to use `get_dummies` from the `str` accessor you parsed it as a string which causes the whole problem.  You took three left turns to make a right turn.  This is much more intuitive to me.  However, `str` is vectorized and will have some performance benefits.  Anyhow, glad I could help